# What would be a good way to sync the timers in all instances of a class?

Tags: c#, timer, singleton, static-classes

That is, I have a class which includes a static System.Threading.Timer, and I want to sync the timers in all the objects. An example would be the following, where what I want to achieve is to have all objects call `DoStuff()` at the same time:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static Timer timer;
    public TestClass() {
        TimerCallback callback = DoStuff;
        timer = new Timer(callback, timer, 0, 500);
    }

    public void DoStuff(object source) {
    // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not valid code.  Anyway, read about "multicast delegate", that together with `System.Timers.Timer` will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. What's not valid about it though? It should just be some renaming, and removed lines from the actual code that works?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to declare member data inside the constructor -- either put it in the class if it should be a member, or remove `public` and `static` keywords if it's intended to be a local variable.

Comment: Ah, yes. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the timer reference is stored in a `static` field, you only ever have one timer instance available at a time. So it's not clear to me what you mean by *"sync the timers [plural]"*.

If you want each instance of the class to execute its `DoStuff()` method on the same tick of a single timer, it seems to me that the right way to do it would be to maintain a single static handler, which calls a delegate instance updated by each instance. For example:

```
public class TestClass {

    private static class TimerHandler
    {
        public static event TimerCallback TimerHandlers;

        private static readonly Timer timer = new Timer(TimerHandlerCallback, null, 0, 500);

        private static void TimerHandlerCallback(object state)
        {
            TimerHandlers?.Invoke(timer);
        }
    }

    public TestClass() {
        TimerHandler.TimerHandlers += DoStuff;
    }

    public void DoStuff(object source) {
    // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Whatever you wind up doing, I see no reason to make the `Timer` field `public`.
- I wrapped the timer in a nested static class, because doing so allows me to expose the timer with an event, which in turn allows me to ignore the question of thread-safe modification of the callback delegate, because the compiler automatically will generate the necessary code for that.
- You were originally passing `timer` as the value to the `state` parameter of the constructor. It's not clear what you intended to happen by that. Here's what *does* happen: the first time the timer is initialized, the field's value is `null`, so the `state` parameter is `null`, and that's what's passed to the handler. With each new instance of `TestClass`, that instance would create a new timer, but use the *previously created* timer instance as the `state` value. In each instance of `TestClass`, when its `DoStuff()` method is called, it would receive the reference to the timer created by the previous instance of a `TestClass` object, or `null` for the first instance of the `TestClass` object created.
  Instead, I simply initialize the timer without a `state` value (passing `null`), and then pass the timer reference itself when invoking the delegate. That makes more sense to me than what your code was doing.
- Static events always have to be used very carefully, because they themselves are always present, and they implicitly retain a reference to any object that subscribes to the event. With the above, your `TestClass` objects will *never* be garbage-collected, because there's no mechanism to unsubscribe an object from the timer event. You may want to consider adding a method to your `TestClass` object that unsubscribes from the event, and which the calling code can call just before it's ready to discard a given `TestClass` object.
  Whether this is actually required, I have no way to know. There's not enough context in your question. If these objects never need to be GC'ed, then you can skip this. If you do need to do this, you might want to consider implementing `IDisposable` as a convenient mechanism for calling the method (i.e. make your `Dispose()` method call it), so a) you can use a `using` statement to handle the lifetime of the object, and b) so that the presence of the interface implementation reminds you that you need to manage the lifetime of the object manually. The one caveat to implementing `IDisposable` here (besides all the usual other caveats) is that you won't be able to rely on the finalizer as a backup to buggy code, because that only works when an object is actually eligible to be GC'ed, which in this case it wouldn't be until you call `Dispose()`.
  Yet another alternative to this issue is to implement the `TimerHandlers` event using weak references. If this is in the context of a WPF program, you could use the `WeakEventManager` class to make this easier. If it's not, you may find it's not worth the trouble to learn how to use weak references correctly, especially in the context of an event. Again, hard for me to say without more context. Either way, the benefit of using weak references is that the reference kept by the event code will not in and of itself prevent the object from being GC'ed. You replace one implementation detail challenge with another; the upside is that the new challenge is more automatic…once you solve it, you're done, rather than having to remember every time you create an instance of the `TestClass` object that you have to clean up after itself later. The downside is of course that conceptually, weak references are likely harder to understand than the basic idea of having to clean up an object before discarding it.